# How to remove Cox Cloud Drive icon from menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Cox cable had a cloud storage system called Cloud Drive. They discontinued it several months ago. The icon is still in my menu bar. Their support services says they no longer support uninstalling it. (Can you believe it?!)

Anyone know how to get rid of it? (Would there be any other files on my Mac relating to it that I should delete, too?)

The icon appears for all log-ins, so it must be system-wide. It can't be removed with Command-Drag, and it doesn't appear in System Preferences > Users and Groups > Log-in Items. Searching for Cloud Drive on the computer doesn't yield any hits. I have tried to find files with that name in Library and System/Library to no avail: searching those folders for Cloud Drive or CloudDrive yield nothing, and I am not sure exactly where to look. I have tried the LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemon folders.

Sure would appreciate any help.

[image: Cox Cloud Drive Icon]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I've just added an answer that may help, but if it doesn't can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/340503/edit) your question to include what you've already tried? Otherwise you may get a lot of suggestions of things you've already done.

Comment: I found the answer through the Apple discussion boards. Turns out it was a file in LaunchDaemons called com.onlinebackup.daemon.plist. I don't know why Cox could not have told me that. Also, that file referenced a program in usr/local/bin called OnlineBackupd. Got rid of that, too.

Comment: That's great! :) Can I encourage you to add an answer to your own question? That way it ensures others can be helped if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a file in LaunchDaemons called com.onlinebackup.daemon.plist.

It can be found at Library/LaunchDaemons/com.onlinebackup.daemon.plist

Opening the file will reveal a reference to another file at usr/local/bin. The usr folder is normally invisible but can be found by going to the Finder and choosing Go > Go to Folder and pasting in the above address.

That file is called OnlineBackupd. Just trash it!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try for any third-party menu bar icon is holding down the <kbd>command</kbd> key while you click on and *drag* the icon totally away from the menu bar.

If this works and then you find it returns after a reboot, I would also check your Login Items at Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items.